# What is causing whitespace on the top & bottom?

Tags: html, css

After I added a new div class for my background image, the top, bottom, and page menus became white. 
**style.css**

```
#boundless{
  background-image:url('http://thehypebr.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/boundless-sem-branco-2.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  line-height:20px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS"; 
  margin:0
}
```

**index.php**

```
<body>
    <div id='boundless' onclick='window.location.href="http://boundlessny.com/clothing"'>
```

Comment: Oh my god! Please format your code properly (indenting by four spaces). Other than that, this is _way_ to much code (and the markup seems to be missing, anyway).

Comment: Fow which selector did you add the class? And where is the relevant HTML? Also a live example would be more than beneficial here. Asking us to trawl through a ton of code isn't very fair! Help us to help you :)

Comment: Try providing a minimal code example that shows your problem. Remove code until you get to the bones of your problem.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What exactly is the intended behaviour?

Comment: Sorry. Before I made the background image as a new div class, the top and bottom didn't have as much whitespace. In fact, the bottom, had none. And the page menus weren't white either.

Comment: Do you mean "Space that is colored white" or actual whitespace, that is the space between elements?

Comment: You'd better to provide the link to your site. There is nothing wrong with the code in your question. You should get basic debugging tools like Firebug before banging your head on a wall. Edit: yep, the problem can be solved by using Firebug and your eyes. The #boundless div does not overlap the previous sibling.

Comment: FYI on your page:Webpage error details
Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 34
Char: 23
Code: 0
URI: http://thehypebr.com/

Comment: It does seem to be colored white (the background color for different elements).

Answer (score 5):

Using Firebug, I found the problem be caused by line 16 in style.css:

```
margin:165px auto 20px;
```

---

How to debug such problems:

1. Think of possible causes, repeat this step after each of the following.
2. Open Firebug by opening a contextmenu on the problematic part (in this case, the blank bottom), and select `Inspect Element`
3. Look Hover over the nodes to see which covers the place in which the problem occurs. I've now got the feeling that a possible cause would be incorrect usage of margin, padding or width.
4. Isolate the CSS / element by looking in the right pane, tab `Style`. If needed, expand a node.
5. Disable or change the value of the CSS property to see if it's actually causing the problem.

Comment: Although I have no idea if this answers the question, I'm just tempted to vote you up because your answer is so nice and clear and gives peace to my heart. Also, +1 for using Firebug on some unidentifiable problem...

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css, you have a number of #xxxxx with

```
background-color:white; and background-color:#fff;
```

example: `#wrapper2` has that.

SO it is doing what you told it to do.